# Photos not synching from iPhone 5S to iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud

I am new to the Apple world and running into difficulty while attempting my Photos from my iPhone 5S (ios version 9.2.1) to iCloud.

In my Photos settings, I have the iCloud Photo Library option selected, yet when I log in to https://www.icloud.com/#photos I do not see any items whatsoever.

I've tried the usual options of restarting my phone, de-selecting and re-selecting etc.

I have noticed that underneath this option it says "Low Disk Space - Uploading 311 items"

What could be going wrong here? Items such as Mail etc are synched up so I'm at a loss

Comment: Photos will only sync when your iPhone is plugged-in and not being used. It can takes hours for pictures to upload to iCloud. Have you given it enough time?  Also, do you have enough free space in iCloud for all your pictures?

Comment: The iPhone has most definitely being plugged in, and there is loads of space available on iCloud.

Answer (score 1):

Try first by checking on your phone on how much your photos are using up in your iCloud by navigating to: **Settings -> iCloud -> Storage xx GB Available -> Manage Storage -> iCloud photo library** and there you'll see there amount of photos and videos you have available in your iCloud.
Uploading photos can take a very long time and there lower upload bandwidth you have the longer it'll take and sometimes it might seem like it stopped uploading but really it might just be uploading a long video clip which could sometimes be a few GB long.
What I've also realized at least with iOS 9.2.1 that navigating away from the photos app might cause they upload process to pause so I'd suggest you that if you feel comfortable to remove the auto lock feature on your iPhone that you should turn that off at least for the time that your doing the bulk uploading by navigating to: **Settings -> General -> Auto-Lock** and select "Never" and then leave your iPhone connected to power with the WiFi connected and within the photo app.
The final verification that you'd want to verify is that you have the adequate amount of storage available on the iCloud account that you're connecting to.